# How do I get a package conditionally executed in Puppet?

Tags: package, exec, puppet, chocolatey

How do I get the packages to execute only if and when `exec['get-chocolatey']` is complete and successful? Right now, the packages try to get executed before the exec command and hence fails with the error reading

> Chocolatey is not functional on the node

I don't get why 'require' doesn't work here.

```
exec { 'get-chocolatey':
    path        => 'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0',
    command     => 'Powershell.exe "Invoke-WebRequest https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | Invoke-Expression"',
    refreshonly => true,
    logoutput   => true
}

package { 'webpi':
    provider => 'chocolatey',
    ensure   => latest,
    require  => Exec['get-chocolatey']
}

package { 'redis-64':
    provider => 'chocolatey',
    ensure   => latest,
    require  => Exec['get-chocolatey']
}
```

Comment: Please add logs (preferably with --debug) from running Puppet to show the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use the Official Chocolatey Installer from the Puppet Provider

Chaining resources works, but why not just use the `chocolatey` class to ensure installation?

https://forge.puppet.com/chocolatey/chocolatey#usage

```
include chocolatey
```

OR

```
class {'chocolatey':
  chocolatey_download_url         => 'https://internalurl/to/chocolatey.nupkg',
  use_7zip                        => false,
  choco_install_timeout_seconds   => 2700,
}
```

#### Organizational Use of Chocolatey.org Packages

If you are an organization, you should be building your own packages or recompiling packages to not use external download and hosting your own internal package server for these packages.

This is due to both trust, control, and a low tolerance of breakages. The following resources provide more context and explanation surrounding the reasoning.

See

- https://chocolatey.org/security#chocolatey.org-packages
- https://chocolatey.org/docs/community-packages-disclaimer
- https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-host-feed

Comment: Hi Rob, I could've done that. I came across the page after I wrote the script but didn't change it as it was working. Quick question please - how do I get Puppet to confirm package install? I get below error: Could not update: Execution of 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe install webpi -y ' returned 4294967295: Installing the following packages: webpi By installing you accept licenses for the packages. webpi v5.0 Installing webpi... Chocolatey timed out waiting for the command to finish. The timeout specified was '2700' seconds. Perhaps try a higher `--execution-timeout`?

Comment: Note that 2700 seconds is 45 minutes. It sounds like the installer isn't completely silent or has some requirement in that it is blocking waiting for input. A higher execution timeout isn't going to make that work for you. I'm going to update my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get the packages to only execute if and when exec['get-chocolatey'] is complete and successful?

You set up resource relationships that require that.  Which you have done with your `require` attributes, and which you could alternatively do with chain operators.

> Right now, the packages try to get executed before the exec command

I think not.  I observe that your `Exec` is marked refreshonly.  Its command will therefore not be executed *at all* unless that resource receives an event from some other resource.  There is nothing in your class that would generate such an event.  It is possible that an event could be received from outside, either directly or by some resource signaling the containing class, but since the command is not running, that seems not to be the case.

> and hence fails with the error reading 'chocolatey is not functional on the node'. I don't get why 'require' doesn't work here.

I see no reason to think that `require` is not working.

I also don't see why you have marked your `Exec` refreshonly.  If you want to arrange for the command to run only if needed, then instead use an appropriate 'unless' or 'onlyif' command, or else use its 'creates' attribute.

Comment: Hi John, you are right. I misunderstood the 'refreshonly' command. My intention was to stop Choco from getting reinstalled every 30 minutes. I was meaning to optimize the script and reduce the execution time. Anyway, removing the refreshonly did the trick and now it works as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Add creates, onlyif or unless to provide a test for the exec resource to ensure idempotent execution.

Answer (score 0):

There's a generalizable form of this dependency that might be helpful in reducing the repetition of the require statement.

This says "get-chocolatey" should happen before any package resource with a Chocolatey provider.

```
Exec['get-chocolatey'] -> Package<| provider == 'chocolatey' |>
```

You can read more about it here.

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#syntax-chaining-arrows

and here

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_collectors.html